# REST API : Can I use (api.in/method/1) this method without any framework in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am using only CORE PHP to send requests to a URL.
Using the url `api.in/?action=method&id=1` is working fine.

My question is can I change my URL to `api.in/method/1` and achieve the same results?
Is this type of getting URL possible? Please help me understand this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Did you try it?

Comment: Yes this is absolutely possible, I'd suggest you look into url rewriting for your server of choice [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Answer (score 1):

normally i'd recommend something like [this](https://github.com/Respect/Rest/blob/master/docs/README.md), but since you insist on `CORE PHP`, just make a folder in the web root named `method`, and then make a folder in the `method` folder named `1`, then make a file called `index.php` in the folder named `1`, then your new `web_root/method/1/index.php` file should be hit when accessing `api.in/method/1`. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hanshenrik** offers the simplest solution. However, if you deploy your scripts outside of the web root then you can use this simple config in nginX and then in your `index.php` include the corresponding script which is appropriate for the API endpoint:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

    location @rewrite {
        # previous query string will be appended unless the replacement path finishes with ? e.g. "/show?user=$1?"
      rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?q=$1 last;
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html last;        
}
```

This config will proxy all URLs to `/api/xxxx` through `/api/index.php` and will return `/index.html` for any non-existing file so that you can use Vue-Router with `mode: history` in your front-end.

index.php:

```
<?php
define('MAIN',dirname(__FILE__));

header('Cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-cache');
if($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'application/json')
{
    $post_input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if($post_input!='') 
    {
        $_POST['json'] = json_decode($post_input,TRUE);
        if(json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE) 
        {
          header('HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid JSON', true, 400); 
          die;
        }
        unset($post_input);
    }
}

if($_GET['q']!='')
{
    if(file_exists($_GET['q'].'.php')) 
    {
      include($_GET['q'].'.php');
    }
    else header('HTTP/1.1 404 File not found', true, 404); 
}
else header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request', true, 400); 

?>
```